# How to make lookup field work in this case without defining the foreign key in the database?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, .net-core

The code is as follows (database first):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] 
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] default newid() NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UserTypeId] [int] NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserTypes] 
(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[UserTypes] ([Id], [Name], [Description]) 
VALUES (1, 'Name1', 'Descr1');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[UserTypes] ([Id], [Name], [Description]) 
VALUES (2, 'Name2', 'Descr2');

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users] ([Id], [Name], [Description], [UserTypeId]) 
VALUES (newid(), 'User1', 'Descr1', 1);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users] ([Id], [Name], [Description], [UserTypeId]) 
VALUES (newid(), 'User2', 'Descr2', 2);
```

C# code:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserType))]
    public int UserTypeId { get; set; }

    public UserType UserType { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserTypes")]
public class UserType
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

`UserTypeId` is mapped, `UserType` is not. Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we consider this as one to many relationship. Then Mapping using dataanotation will be like this.

```
public partial class User
{
    [Key]
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int UserTypeId { get; set; }
    public UserType UserType { get; set; }
}

public partial class UserType
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserTypeId")]
    public System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And to query

```
var data = await _dbcontext.Users.Include(x => x.UserType).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I have tested this. But I put table name mapping in context model override

Comment: I see now, my bad. I wonder if there is any way to make it work without calling Include()?

Comment: To be honest, at the very first time doing ef, i thought the same. so far include is the way to do it.

Comment: And there is no way to make it load all the related entities without specifying each one explicitly?

Comment: You can use lazy loading, but then it will run another query to load usertypes.